# How to compare two list of dictionary values present in any index

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have two list of dictionaries

```
dict1 = [{'Weight': '134.0', 'date': '2017-06-15 17:44:29', 'model': '2011', 'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}, {'Weight': '14.0', 'date': '2017-06-15 16:21:09', 'model': '2011', 'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}, {'Weight': '154.0', 'date': '2017-06-15 16:21:09', 'model': '2011', 'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}, {'Weight': '184.0', 'date': '2017-06-15 15:47:49', 'model': '2011', 'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}, {'Weight': '104.0', 'date': '2017-06-15 17:11:09', 'model': '2011', 'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}, {'Weight': '134.0', 'date': '2017-06-15 17:27:49', 'model': '2011', 'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}]
dict2 = [{'Weight': '124.0', 'date': '2017-06-15 17:35:19', 'model': '2011', 'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}, {'Weight': '184.0', 'date': '2017-06-15 15:47:49', 'model': '2011', 'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}, {'Weight': '114.0', 'date': '2017-06-15 17:11:09', 'model': '2011', 'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}, {'Weight': '14.0', 'date': '2017-06-15 16:21:09', 'model': '2011', 'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}]
```

result should be matched in one list of dictionary and non matched should be in other dictionary

*example*:

```
matched:   [{'Weight': '14.0', 'date': '2017-06-15 16:21:09', 'model': '2011', 'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}]
nonmatched: [{'Weight': '124.0', 'date': '2017-06-15 17:35:19', 'model': '2011', 'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}, {'Weight': '184.0', 'date': '2017-06-15 15:47:49', 'model': '2011', 'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}, {'Weight': '114.0', 'date': '2017-06-15 17:11:09', 'model': '2011', 'serialnumber': 'SN_WEIGHT082', 'unit': 'Kg', 'manufacturer': 'CONTINUA'}]
```

Comment: care to even format your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this. 
- `matched = [ x for x in dict1 if x in dict2 ]` 
- `unmatched = [ x for x in dict1 if x not in dict2 ]`

Comment: add your comments in the comment section

Comment: have one more question,

i have 
DEFINITION ={"date":"date","unit":"Pound","model":"model","manufacturer":"manufacturer","serialnumber":"serialnumber","Weight":"Weight123"}
TEMPLATE = 
{
  "serialId": "serialnumber",
  "dataType": "WEIGHT",
  "data": {
    "type": "WEIGHT",
    "uni": "Pound",
    "date": "date",
    "model": "model",
    "manufacturer": "manufacturer",
    "serialnumber": "serialnumber",
    "Weight": "Weight123"
  },
  "timeStamp": "date"
}

how to create a new dictionary by comparing both and common values present in both.